Merge many large tables in PostgreSQL
I have 150 tables with the same columns representing areas in a country. The size of each table is millions of rows and tens of GB in size.
I want to combine all the tables into one with the aim of improving and increasing the accuracy of the spatial operations that I perform. What is the most efficient way in terms of speed and storage to combine these tables in PostgreSQL?
For example I have Table 1:
fid    column-1   column-n   geom
-----------------------------------------
1      001        ...        geometry-001
2      002        ...        geometry-002

Table 2:
fid    column-1   column-n   geom
-----------------------------------------
1      003        ...        geometry-003
2      004        ...        geometry-004

Expected merged table:
fid    column-1   column-n   geom
-----------------------------------------
1      001        ...        geometry-001
2      002        ...        geometry-002
3      003        ...        geometry-003
4      004        ...        geometry-004

The way I am thinking is to insert tables 2,3,4,5,..,150 into table 1, then delete tables 2,3,4,5,...150
However, this will take a long time and take up quite a lot of storage, so is there a better way?

I don't think there is a simpler way.


However, this will take a long time and take up quite a lot of storage, so is there a better way?

You could delete migrated tables along the way instead of deleting only at the end, that would minimize storage need.
Also, you should disable all indices and check constraints in the target table during the migration: as long as you are sure your migration code is correct, that does make things quite faster (reactivating indexes once the migration is done will rebuild the index, which is way faster than the indexing at each insertion: similarly for the check constraints).

Thank you for the response, as I thought tbh. When we drop (cascade) a table, will it also delete tuples and pages in PostgreSQL so it reclaims space?

@HermawanWiwid  Cascading and having relationships adds complication but the idea remains the same as for the check constraints: drop all relationships and reinstate the needed ones to the new table afterwards: just factor in any processing and clean up that is needed...  --  I dont' think dropping tables drops database-level definitions the tables depend upon (e.g. data types), vice versa, table-level objects should indeed all be dropped: but I'd have to double-check PostgreSql docs for the details of that.
